# Building "whats new"

Tags: php, project

I am building a simple and small project management tool in PHP/MySQL which includes:

```
1-> Projects
1.1-> Tasks
1.1.1-> Task Comments
1.1.2-> Task Notes
1.1.3-> Task Files
```

So every user logs in to their account and see what tasks they are assigned to etc.

When a user login, I want to show "whats new" on their dashboard like below:

```
"5 New comments posted to task xyz"
"3 New files added to task abc"
etc...
```

The new stuff needs to be shown from the time they log off previously.

Is there any good third-party solutions to achieve this?
Any suggestions and ideas will be warmly welcomed.

Thanks

Example:
A user ABC was assigned to 10 tasks. The last time he logged in was 5 days ago. Now to day he logs in again. During this period, lot of activity has happened. 5 "new" comments have been posted to "Task 1" that he did not see. 3 Notes have been added to "Task 2" that he did not see.

So what I want a function that shows the activity during the past 5 days so that a user knows what has happened during his absence.

I can create something using local database but that will involve frequent database transactions. So I wanted to know if any third party service store the whole activity and return it whenever I need.

Can this be done with "Pusher (pusher.com)" ?

Comment: try trello.com you might not have to build your system afterall :)

Comment: ??? You can't just make a story board with every element attached to users and just load the first new 30 elements witch matches with the user id!?

Comment: How do you define **new** in this case? Is new everything that has been `created` since the last login ([Tarilo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14253596/1110760)) or is it new until the time the user has `seen` the comment/post or what so ever? In that case you will need a new table which logs the users activity.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a `project management system`.

You can try any of the following:

1. [basecamp.com](http://basecamp.com/)
2. [trello.com](https://trello.com/)

I have used both the above sites and they are good.

Comment: the above sites are full "project management solutions". I want to build "whats new" (explained above) that can be used with other stuff like my blog etc...

Comment: This is no answer, sometimes reinventing the wheel makes it better so let him. of course you could give an command explaining that there are a ton of good project managers free to use on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is probably something like this

```
SELECT count(*) FROM task_comments 
  WHERE task='your_task_id' 
  AND creation_date > (SELECT last_login FROM users WHERE user='user_id');
```

Note that this will need to be altered to fit your database schema. I'm not sure if the date comparison works like this, but that shouldn't be to hard figure out.

You will need to run a query for every entry that can be added to a task, so you will need one for comments, notes and files.